# Bounding uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, uniform-continuity

> Show that if $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then there is an $L > 0$ such that $$|f(x)| \leq L \cdot (1 + |x|).$$

I'm quite stuck here. Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926512/bounds-for-uniformly-continuous-function?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is uniformly continuous, and take $\varepsilon=1$. There exists some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq 1$$ whenever $|x-y|\leq \delta$.

Fix any $x\geq0$ (the negative case is identical), and let $n = \left\lfloor\frac{x}{\delta}\right\rfloor$, so that $|x-n\delta| \leq \delta$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
|f(x)|&\leq |f(0)|+|f(x)-f(0)| \leq |f(0)|+|f(x)-f(n\delta)|+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f((k+1)\delta)-f(k\delta)|\\
&\leq|f(0)| + 1+n
\end{align*}$$
But we know that $n\leq \frac{x}{\delta}$, so we get
$$\begin{align*}
|f(x)|&\leq|f(0)| + 1+ \frac{x}{\delta} \leq \max(1/\delta, |f(0)| + 1)\cdot (1+x)
\end{align*}$$
and we can just take $L=\max(1/\delta, |f(0)| + 1)$ to conclude.

Comment: Where this inequation come from?:
\begin{align*}
|f(0)|+|f(x)-f(n\delta)|+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f((k+1)\delta)-f(k\delta)|
&\leq|f(0)| + \delta+n\cdot \delta
\end{align*}
I think that it will be
\begin{align*}
|f(0)|+|f(x)-f(n\delta)|+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|f((k+1)\delta)-f(k\delta)|
&\leq|f(0)| +1+n
\end{align*}

Comment: You're right, I added $\delta$'s where there shouldn't be any (this doesn't change the conclusion, just the setting of $L$). Let me fix that. @Chris

Comment: This should be fixed now, @Chris. Thanks for spotting this!